# Javascript code execution sequence

Tags: javascript

```js
    function User(firstName,EmailId){
          this.name = firstName;
          this.email = EmailId;
          this.quizScores = [];
          this.currentScore = 0;
    }
    User.prototype = {
          constructor : User,
          saveScore:function (scoreToAdd)  {
             this.quizScores.push(scoreToAdd)
          },
          showNameAndScores:function ()  {
             var scores = this.quizScores.length > 0 ? this.quizScores.join(",") : "No Scores Yet";
             return this.name + " Scores: " + scores;
          },
          changeEmail:function (newEmail)  {
             this.email = newEmail;
             return "New Email Saved: " + this.email;
          }
    }

    secondUser = new User("Peter", "Peter@examnple.com");
    console.log('secondUser',secondUser);
    secondUser.changeEmail("Richard@examnple.com");
    secondUser.saveScore(18);
    secondUser.showNameAndScores();
```

On my console I see output as

```
currentScore:0
email:"Richard@examnple.com"
name:"Peter"
quizScores:[18]
```

Now in my above code I have created object and then immediate printed on console then I have called prototype methods still it print values updated by prototype methods.why it happens?

Before expand this object
[image]

After Expand this object 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why it happens?

`console.log`, when passed an object, prints a "live" object, a reference to it (at least in chrome and firefox). If you later update that object and only *then* expand the object in the console, you'll see the updated values. To get the current state of the object, you could print the properties individually, for example:

```
 console.log(secondUser.email)
```

Another possibility is printing a deep copy of an object, not the object itself.

Comment: Thanks Sergio.Its helpful

Comment: @GitaramKanawade: JFYI, you're expected to accept helpful answers. (the green checkmark on the left)

Comment: @GitaramKanawade: you should also go through your past questions and upvote/accept where appropriate.